# Trigonometric differentiability

Tags: calculus

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^3 \sin(1/x),  & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\
0, & \text{if } x = 0
\end{cases}$

Show that the function is differentiable at $x = 0$.

Using the derivative definition I get $\lim \limits_{h \to 0} f(x) = \frac{h^3\sin(1/h)-0}{h}$ $=$  $\lim \limits_{h \to 0} h^2\sin(1/h)$

but isn't that undefined? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0 \leq |h^{2} \sin (\frac 1 h)| \leq |h|^{2} \to 0$ so the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$\left|h^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)\right|\leq |h|^2.$$

Actually, your function is twice differentiable at 0.